# TypeError: None is not valid value for the expected return type integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Solution:
    def maxRepeating(self, sequence: str, word: str) -> int:
        k = 0
        check = word
        for x in range(len(sequence)//len(word)):
            if sequence.count(check) >= 1:
                check = check + word
                k += 1
            else:
                return k
                break
```

When word is 'ab' and sequence is 'ababab' expected output is 3 but error message pops up.

Comment: TypeError: None is not valid value for the expected return type integer
    raise TypeError(str(ret) + " is not valid value for the expected return type integer");
Line 41 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 48 in <module> (Solution.py)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
Line 14 in _serialize_int (./python3/__serializer__.py)
Line 63 in _serialize (./python3/__serializer__.py)
    out = ser._serialize(ret, 'integer')
Line 39 in _driver (Solution.py)

Comment: Please [edit] to add details. Comments don't support fancy formatting.

Comment: What is your program supposed to do? Don't expect us to know all tasks from leetcode by heart.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but this isn't a question. Please read [ask] and [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Is this error from type-checking with e.g. mypy, rather than a runtime exception?  if so it will be because there are some cases where the method reaches the end of the loop without explicitly returning anything. Also the `break` after `return k` is redundant.

Comment: @DarkKnight why is it broken?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a TypeError from your linter probably because you put `int` has the expected return type when you defined the function.

I fixed a bunch of things, including removing inefficient code, fixing premature termination of the loop & overall code simplicity.
Please try to make your question more detailed next time.

Here's the solution to your problem:

```
class Solution:
    def maxRepeating(self, sequence: str, word: str) -> int:
        k = 0
        check = word
        while check in sequence:
            check += word
            k += 1
        return k
```